# Issue invoking a Web Application built using GWT 1.6 in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, gwt, war, tomcat6

I have downloaded a WAR of a working web application whose UI is built using GWT 1.6.

### Inside the WAR

[image]

When I try to access the app from the server thru it's url http://dummy.com/app, it automatically directs to http://dummy.com/app/html/com.my.domain.home/home.html and it's works flawlessly.

But when I try to deploy the same war to my local tomcat (same version as that of the server), I don't see the app getting invoked in http://localhost:8080/app and also not getting invoked even when I access http://localhost:8080/app/html/com.my.domain.home/home.html

1. Any guidance on how to deploy a WAR of this structure into local Tomcat?
2. How I can Invoke this Web application in local tomcat where I am able to run other small web application.

Comment: Have you checked http://localhost:8080 ? Can you show in you question folder structure from your webapp folder ?

Comment: Yes, I checked localhost:8080 and it loads tomcat's homepage as expected but when I navigate to the app like localhost:8080/app, I get 404 error.

Also uploaded the folder structure for your reference.

Comment: Ok two things, first try http://localhost:8080/App Uppercase letter is miningful. If it wouldn't help then please list also your WEB-INF/web.xml file

Comment: does it resolve your problem ?

Comment: Actually the problem was something else and I just figured it out.

The project was referring some libraries which is available in the server and not in the local so I packaged them into WEB-INF/lib and it worked.

Thanks for your time!